# How do I determine if an Excel range is hidden?

Tags: vba, excel

In my code I include a boolean variable in which I want to assign the value of a range's hidden property. i.e. if the range is hidden, the variable should have the value true, and vice versa.

While running the code I get a '1004' Run-time error - Unable to get the Hidden property of the Range class. By this I assume that Hidden property in this case is write-only (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there a way to determine (in my code, not by watching) whether a range/cell is hidden or not?

I have a class named "minas" and with this sub I am trying to create a collection of minas based on some criteria.

```
Public mines As Collection
Sub existing_months()
    Set mines = New Collection
    Dim min As minas
    Dim str As String
    Dim x As Range
    Dim y As Boolean
    For i = 1 To 12
        Set min = New minas
        Set x = Range("A1:A500").Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If x Is Nothing Then GoTo next_iteration:
        y = x.Hidden 'does not get the property
        Call min.initialize(x, y)
        str = min.minas & "/" & min.etos
        mines.Add min, str
        Debug.Print min.ref_range.Address & " " & min.end_cell
next_iteration:
    Next
    Set min = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you see my note in my answer about using Find in hidden cells?  Your current code won't work for hidden cells as is.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Seemed an easy-one. I mis understood whose member hidden property is. I marked as answer  Chrismas007's, as he featured an other problem of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a quick Google search, `Range.Find` will not find the data if the cell is hidden if you use `LookIn:=xlValues`.  I tested this with "Test" in Cell `A6` and hid the row.  This code returned `Nothing`:

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim x As Range
    Set x = Range("A1:A7").Find("Test", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If x Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing"
    Else
        If x.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            MsgBox x.Address & " is Hidden"
        Else
            MsgBox x.Address & " is Visible"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Instead you need to use `LookIn:=xlFormulas`:**

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim x As Range
    Set x = Range("A1:A7").Find("Test", , xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    If x Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing"
    Else
        If x.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            MsgBox x.Address & " is Hidden"
        Else
            MsgBox x.Address & " is Visible"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you can use either:

```
y = x.EntireRow.Hidden
```

or

```
y = x.EntireColumn.Hidden
```

to get your Boolean (True if the cell is hidden and False if the cell is visible)

Answer (score 9):

You can say a **cell** is hidden if it is located on a hidden row or hidden column.
Then a **range** is hidden if all cells in that range are hidden:

```
Public Function IsHidden(rIn As Range) As Boolean
    Dim r As Range
    IsHidden = True
    For Each r In rIn
        If Not r.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            If Not r.EntireColumn.Hidden Then
                IsHidden = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to determine if the entire column is hidden? Individual cells can not be hidden. (Unless, of course, you're referring to the HiddenFormula property). If so, the following code should work:

```
y = x.entirecolumn.Hidden 'does not get the property
```

Let me know if this works