# Excel VBA: Autofit column only for visible rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have filter function that show me different rows depending what i write in a search field. I then print these rows and before that I want to autofit a column (W) because the text in that field can sometime be long and sometime be short. If its short I want to autofit the column before print to save space.

I have tried some functions that contain .EntireColumn.AutoFit but that take the hidden rows in to account and then autofit as they where visible.

Example:

```
With Range("W4:W1400").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
```

Or this:

```
Dim mCell As Range
For Each mCell In Range("W2:W2")
    mCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   ' If mCell.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth > 50 Then _
   ' mCell.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 50
Next mCell
```

Here is also an extra bonus, IF the column contains an extra long text, the column (W) should only stretch to 50.

:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine if an Excel range is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074975/how-do-i-determine-if-an-excel-range-is-hidden)

Comment: Maybe, with this I can filter the visible rows, but when I apply the AutoFit for the column, its still applies for all the cells in that columns, not only the visible ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AutoFit` will always set the column width using the widest text, no matter if cells are visible or not.
Best bet is to copy only the visible cells to a (hidden) sheet, use Autofit on that column and assign the calculated column width to your column. The following routine will do that, it assumes that there is a sheet named "tmp" in your workbook and that the data. If you want, you can pass an optional min or max column width.

```
Sub AutofitVisible(r As Range, Optional minWidth As Double = 0, Optional maxWidth As Double = 0)
    Dim tmpSheet As Worksheet
    Set tmpSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tmp")
    tmpSheet.UsedRange.Clear
    ' Copy only the visible cells
    r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    With tmpSheet.Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll  ' Copy the visible cells (with formatting)
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit     ' Autofit that data
        Dim colWidth As Double    
        colWidth = .ColumnWidth
        If minWidth > 0 And minWidth > colWidth Then colWidth = minWidth
        If maxWidth > 0 And maxWidth < colWidth Then colWidth = maxWidth
    
        r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = colWidth ' Set column width of orig. data
    End With
End Sub
```

The call would look like this:

```
AutofitVisible  Range("W4:W1400"), maxWidth := 50
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel it'll be easier to just have a temporary sheet used to check the temporary column width than to loop.

```
Sub limitWidthColW()
    Dim lRow As Long, rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Me.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change your sheet, "Me" = ThisWorkbook, also change as needed
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.FilterMode Then '**
        Set ws2 = Me.Worksheets.Add(After:=Me.Worksheets(Me.Worksheets.Count))
        Set rng = ws.Range("W1:W" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        
        rng.Copy ws2.Range("A1")
        ws2.Range("A1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Dim colWidth2 As Long
        colWidth2 = ws2.Range("A2").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
        If colWidth2 > 50 Then colWidth2 = 50 'bonus!
        ws.Range("W2").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = colWidth2
        'Cleaning up
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws2.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else '**
        ws.Columns("W:W").AutoFit '**
    End If '**
End Sub
```

This also resets the autofit for Column W without creating/deleting a temporary sheet if no filter is applied. Delete the '**-lines if you don't want this to happen.